# How to center the text relative to the button, but not centered in the container?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with positioning a button. When I try to add a code like this `margin-left: 15px` to the css of the button ,nothing happens,and in the browser (inspector mode),I see the code is crossed out.
Can someone tell me what block this code?

What I am trying to do is to to center the text relative to the button. So an example: I have a text "Something" which is almost perfectly centered relative to the button. But if I type something else like "Something new!", the text will start where the button starts. But I want to look like this:
[image]

So if I type any text,the button will be always at the center of the text.

Here is the source code:

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: #000000;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.details h3 {
    color: #e5e5e5;
    display:contents;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    font-weight:700;
}
.details {
    position: relative;
    top: 45%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.details button {
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000000;
    border: none;
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
button {
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>

<div class="details">
<h3>Something</h3>

<div class="button"></div>
<button>Some text!</button>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ***Don't*** add `!important` to *anything* unless it is totally unavoidable! It breaks the "cascading" part of cascading style sheets and makes it even harder to make further changes. I don't see code anywhere that is actually trying to center the button, the header, or anything in fact?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I get that you want the text and button center aligned with each other, but they are currently being displayed to the left of the screen... do you still want them to appear at the left instead of fully centered? If so, what are the requirements, e.g. is there a specific column or width that it needs to fit into? Do you have other content in `display` because you have set `flex-direction` or it - do you need that for dome other purpose?

Comment: The `margin-left: 15px;` is crossed out because you have a `margin-left: 0px;` beneath it. In your image, the `margin-left: 0px;` is crossed out because you're adding a `margin-left: 44px;` directly into the element. You'd need to read about [style hierarchy](https://dev.to/iraamoni/css-style-hierarchy-6dg).

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do? there so many mistakes, the link to the stylesheet belogns into the head not between body and head. Then a divbox without content wont style anything. a button is only needed if you need it to work for JS. Otherwise use a divbox to be styled as a button for a link as example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. You want to centre-align the text and button with each other in the `details` div
2. The `details` div is to be placed at the left of the screen 50px from the left
3. `details` has other content or is part of something bigger, as you are using `flex-direction` - therefore changing the css for that class might affect something else that we can't see.

You can add an inline block around the elements to centre, e.g. add a div using this css:

```
.details .centred-block{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The `text-align:center` centres the contents of the div (obviously!), and the `inline-block` means that this div will only be as big as it's contents, so the text and button will only be centre-aligned with *each other* - they won't be centred across the whole width of `details`.

**Working examples:**

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
}
.details p, h2 {
  color: #FFF;
}

.details h3 {
  color: #e5e5e5;
  display: contents;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.details {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.details .centred-block{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}

.details .centred-block-fixed-width{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #FF0;
  width: 200px;
}

.details button {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000000;
  border: none;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

button {}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="details">

    <div class="centred-block">
      <h3>Something</h3>
      <div class="button"></div>
      <button>Some text!</button>
    </div>

    <p>Example with wider text:</p>
    <div class="centred-block">
      <h3>Something Else</h3>

      <div class="button"></div>
      <button>Some text!</button>
    </div>

    <h2>UPDATED</h2>
    <p>Example with fixed width centred block so the button is always in the same place:</p>
    <div class="centred-block-fixed-width">
      <h3>Something</h3>

      <div class="button"></div>
      <button>Some text!</button>
    </div>

    <p>Example with longer text:</p>
    <div class="centred-block-fixed-width">
      <h3>Something Else </h3>

      <div class="button"></div>
      <button>Some text!</button>
    </div>
    
    <p>BUT! with a fixed width, the text <i>will wrap</i> if it gets too long:</p>
    <div class="centred-block-fixed-width">
      <h3>Something Longer</h3>

      <div class="button"></div>
      <button>Some text!</button>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Also, as [Islam Elshobokshy pointed out in the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9942418/islam-elshobokshy), You are overriding `margin-left` further down the *same* class - (I've removed this from the CSS above altogether as it was unnecessary).

```
.details button {
    margin-left: 15px;       /* HERE.... */
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000000;
    border: none;
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;         /* AND AGAIN HERE.... */
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One question: Is there a way to do this without changing the position of the button on the screen?
So I mean, the width of the text will increase when I have enter longer text.

Comment: @StereoMC If the button is going to be centred in the middle of the text, and then the text gets longer, the button is going to have to move so it stays centered, isn't it? You can make the `inline-block` a fixed width, that means the centre is always in the same place, but then the space to the left of the text will (obviously) change, and it also means the text will wrap if it gets too long.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code is you are calling the margin-left two times. Remove the one beneath it `margin-left: 0`.

You are good to go